# System.IO.Ports 5.0 Xamarin.Forms Serial Port not supported

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, serial-port

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app that reads data from an external device via RS232 -> USB.  I was looking for how to read from a Serial port and ran into System.IO.Ports which says it will work with .netstandard2.0 and has MonoAndroid1.0, MonoTouch, Xamarin.iOS, ... support.  I'm running Xamarin forms 4.8 (will upgrade to 5 soon) which implements netstandard2.0 when targeting Android 8+ and I'm targeting 9 so I'm not sure why this doesn't work.  When I try to new up a serial port, it throws an exception

`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows.'`

What's even more confusing, is the MS Doc site says that it supports
.NET Framework 2.0 - 4.8
.NET Platform 2.1 - 5.0
Xamarin.Mac 3.0

The Nuget package says it supports
.netstandard 2.0
.netcoreapp2.1
monoandroid
monotouch
xamarin.mac
xamarin.ios

The github page has implementations for linx, mac, windows, ... so not sure why the exception explicitly says only for windows.

Microsoft Doc site:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Github: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports

Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/

Comment: It seems that System.IO.Ports.SerialPort will be available in Xamarin next year's release of .NET 6.0. [Announcing .NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/)

Comment: Where in the link does it say that?

Comment: The article I introduced states about seven times that Xamarin will be available in the release of .NET 6.0. Also, on Microsoft's documentation site, the only Xamarin that can use SerialPort is Xamarin.Mac 3.0. [SerialPort Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) And .NET Standard is not listed.

Comment: What are you talking about.  Xamarin will not be available in .NET 6.0 - it will migrate to MAUI and it does not say anywhere about System.IO.Ports in that article anywhere.  I see now what you are referencing on the document site, but on nuget, it shows different dependencies.  Not sure what that's about.

Comment: If you search the article for the word "Xamarin", it will appear seven times. If the sentence containing "Xamarin" doesn't fit your idea, it wouldn't make sense. You're probably right that .NET 6.0 isn't Xamarin. However, it has the same features and specifications as current Xamarin, so now you have to write separate applications using different frameworks, but .NET 6.0 is a single that can support all kinds of devices. You can probably create an application. Such applications could also support SerialPort.

Comment: I'm glad you're able to use the find feature for random keywords that are not really helpful.  Xamarin already exists and supposedly - from nuget package - can target Xamarin successfully.  I see your link to the docs says otherwise.  That's quite confusing.  The nuget package is actual code and packaged to describe what it can be used with.  Docs are not in any way attached to the code so I'm more suspect of the docs than the package, but clearly something isn't lining up.  Nuget package here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/ says netstandard2.0 and Xamarin and monoandroid

Comment: Since there are SerialStream.Unix.cs, SerialPort.Linux.cs, SerialPort.FreeBSD.cs in [the folder of GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports) that you presented, the number of supported OS may be increasing. However, SerialPort.iOS.cs, SerialPort.Android.cs, and the corresponding SerialStream.Xxxx.cs do not exist, so it seems that they are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Because Xamarin.Forms is using .Net Standard as Target Framework. And System.IO.Ports is not supported in .Net Standard.

You could use `UsbDeviceConnection` instead. This class is used for sending and receiving data and control messages to a USB device. For more details, please check the MS document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.hardware.usb.usbdeviceconnection?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

You could download the source file from the link below. [Xamarin.Forms: Read Data using UsbDeviceConnection Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772270/xamarin-forms-read-data-using-usbdeviceconnection-library)

Comment: Yes it is supported in .net standard.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/  it says clearly .netstandard 2.0 along with monoandroid etc as indicated in my original question.

Comment: Also, here we can see implementations for Linux, Mac, Windows, ... https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports so it seems like it should at least not give the above error.

Comment: @MPavlak, I think you and Wendy are both correct in different ways.  You are correct in that you have code you can compile; Wendy is likely correct in that .NET Standard does not support it.  This is confusing, and is mentioned in this doc under [.NET Standard problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#net-standard-problems).

Comment: To quote: "Platform-unsupported exceptions at run time / .NET Standard exposes platform-specific APIs. Your code might compile without errors and appear to be portable to any platform even if it isn't portable. When it runs on a platform that doesn't have an implementation for a given API, you get run-time errors."